# After upgrading to Windows 10 version 1809, PowerShell does not save font and transparency settings

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-v1809

Like the title says, I upgraded to Windows 10 version 1809 from version 1803. Now PowerShell does not save transparency setting at all (I set it to 90%) and does not save my font settings when I set it to "Consolas" ("Courier New" works).

The transparency is also a problem with Command Prompt and WSL console as well, but these 2 do not have a problem with setting the font to "Consolas".

Answer (score 6):

I found that changing the setting in the registry works.  If I change transparency through the properties window, the setting doesn't stick; it reverts to opaque the next time I open a command prompt window like you're seeing.

To change the setting in the registry, run regedit.exe, click on the drop-down arrow next to "HKEY_CURRENT_USER", and then click on "Console".  The setting on the right side is named "WindowAlpha".  I changed the value to e6 (decimal 230) which corresponds to 90% transparent.  To change the value, just double-click on "WindowAlpha".  Click "OK" when you're done and the setting should be saved.  Open a Command Prompt window and see if the window is transparent; hopefully it works for you too!

Comment: I ended up modifying the settings from the Registry as well, but this did not work with the font; PowerShell still does not respect the changes I did to its console in the Registry.

Comment: whats the value for 75%

Comment: This doesn't work - transparency still not saved

Comment: Setting the opacity via the registry appears to work for me, FWIW.

Comment: @NULL.Dude Windows calculator has a hex converter